# ionic framework - no smooth springy scroll effect on Android

Tags: ionic-framework

My problem is when i deploy my `ionic` app on android, that *smooth springy* scroll effect (see `.gif` below) **is missing**. This does not occur when i serve my app locally on my development environment.

#### Why is it missing and how can i enable it?

My development environment:

- ionic `1.3.20` and `1.0.0-rc.3` as a bower dependency
- android sdk `22`
- ubuntu `14.10`
- java version `1.8.0_25`
- Ant version `1.9.4`

---

This `.gif` illustrates what i'm referring as *smooth springy* scroll effect:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You experiencing this because on iOS and Local-Browser the default setting for this effect is to be enabled while on Android the default is to be disabled.

**To change that**, add `has-bouncing="true"` attribute to `ion-content` tag

*for example:*

```
<ion-content has-bouncing="true">
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ion-content element like this:

```
<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="false" has-bouncing="true">
```

Comment: isn't that what's [Karan Kumar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29805655/3191896) says?

Comment: I tried his solution but without 'overflow-scroll="false"' it didn't work