# How do I get native smooth scrolling using Ionic, Angular and Cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Here's my environment:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
- AngularJs: 1.4.8
- Ionic: 1.1.1
- Test mobile device: Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1 (The goal is that the app should work in Android and iOS, but not tested in iOS yet)

I have a finite list of ionic cards created by ng-repeat. The problem is that:

- I don't get a scrollbar at all
- I don't get a smooth native scroll over the list as shown in the gif in this post: [ionic framework - no smooth springy scroll effect on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803701/ionic-framework-no-smooth-springy-scroll-effect-on-android) , The scroll works but it's sort of dry, I don't get that feeling of when you scroll rapidly, and the scroll is fast in the beginning and then it slows down until it stops, just like scrolling in native apps like the Gmail app, I hope you understand what I mean, Instead, when I scroll, it's like shifting the page up and down.

I use

> overflow-scroll="true"

and

> has-bouncing="true" , as suggested in this post: [ionic framework - no smooth springy scroll effect on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803701/ionic-framework-no-smooth-springy-scroll-effect-on-android)

in my ion-content. Here's my code:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="CountryController as controller" overflow-scroll="true" has-bouncing="true">          
        <div class="list card">
            <div ng-repeat="country in controller.countries" class="item custom-item">
                <div class="item-avatar custom-item-avatar">
                    <img ng-src="images/flags/{{::country.abbr}}.png" />
                    <p>{{::country.name}}</p>                        
                </div>               
            </div>
        </div>
```

and I have even this config in my index.js to disable jsScrolling:

```
    angular.module('app', ['ionic']).config(function ($ionicConfigProvider) {
        $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);           
    });
```

What am I missing here? Is it what I get with ionic or am I supposed to get the real native scrolling? Any clues is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: are making a `debug` build or a `release build`. There is a big difference in performance. debug builds are often slower as the debugging is running alongside your app. try a release build if you have not yet.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon: I just did a release build, no difference, still no scrollbar and no smooth scrolling.

Comment: Have you tried using `ion-scroll` for list card where data is in `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: I have the same problem. For me, setting jsScrolling to true actually provided a much more fluent scroll experience. However, it seems like everybody recommends native scrolling for performance reasons. Did you manage to find a solution, i.e. use native scrolling and at the same time achieve fluent scrolling?

Comment: @LonelyDeveloper, any solution you got, please update for readers for help.